# read arrays in google sheet json response in php

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

```
$url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/...';
$json= file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
$obj = $obj->{'values'};     
print_r( $obj);
```

Response from google sheet is like :

```
{ "range": "Recipes!D10:E10", "majorDimension": "ROWS", "values": [ [ "65", "122.9" ] ] }
```

After i decode the response with lines of code above,it is like this :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 65 [1] => 122.9 ) )    

// How to extract the data "65" and "122.9" from this decoded response ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
$obj = $obj->{'values'};
```

which contains:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
               [0] => 65 
               [1] => 122.9
          )
```

So `$obj[0]` contains:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 65 
    [1] => 122.9  
)
```

and obviously

```
$obj[0][0] => 65
$obj[0][1] => 122.9
```

Comment: Thank you buddy for the help ! That resolved the problem. Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 1):

you simply missed a couple of array levels

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
$values = $obj->values[0];     

echo $values[0] . PHP_EOL;
echo $values[1];
```

RESULT

```
65
122.9
```

Comment: Thank you buddy for the help ! That resolved the problem. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

If we look closely at the doc here : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php,
You need to pass true for an Assoc array instance of a simple array. So you should do something like json_decode($json, true) and you should be good to go ! Then get $obj['values'][0][0] and $obj['values'][0][1]